# Mongo driver persistence issue in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am running multiple map reduce programs(Having records more than 20 lakhs) where each mapper uses a mongo instance for inserting records to mongo collections of database 'test'. I can see the object id(I am logging it) getting created. When I check the mongo database,there are no documents with those object id. The mongo instance that I am running is 2.2 .

On further investigating, I came to know that the object id are created by the mongo driver. I am not understanding why the documents are not getting persisted.

Comment: Can you show sample code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: The issue occurs when there are multiple mappers or threads writing to the same mongo database. This issue is very inconsistent and I could reproduce few times. I am using simple mongo connection to connect and insert in each mapper                                           Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017); 
DB db = mongo.getDB("test_service"); DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");                               
DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.put("name", "xx");
coll.insert();

Comment: Are you using different `Mongo` instances across the different threads?  You should treat `Mongo` as a singleton and use the same one for all the mappers/threads.